# Error while running jar as a service on ubuntu

Tags: bash, services

I am trying to run a simple jar file as a service in Ubuntu.

Below is the content of my bash script (/opt/ashish/ser/my-webapp.sh) which runs jar

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/bin/java -jar Main.jar
```

and below is the text in my service file

```
[Unit]
Description=My Webapp Java REST Service
[Service]
User=administrator
# The configuration file application.properties should be here:
#change this to your workspace
WorkingDirectory=/opt/ashish/ser
#path to executable. 
#executable is a bash script which calls jar file
ExecStart=/bin/bash /opt/ashish/ser/my-webapp.sh
SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Below is the error I get when I try to run the service.

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [administrator]
```

Below is the reference link which I used to create a service.

https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-java-application-as-a-service-on-ubuntu

Comment: Looks like your program needs a terminal to auth the user of some sort!

Comment: You did well for following that link but your script is run as `sudo` and that requires authentication so it will need a terminal to do that